# Finding values array and counting it

Tags: javascript

I have an array, I have loop into the array and find the values which are having values '100,0 or rest' in a row.

```
 var num100=100,num0=0,rest,count100=0,count0=0,countrest=0;
 var array1= [
 /* Reduced data set */
 [ "Manoj", 100, 1, 1, 1 ],
 [ "Jai", 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
 [ "Pradeep", 1, 1, 1, 1 ],
 [ "Reena", 0, 0, 0, 0 ],
 [ "Santos", 100, 1, 1, 1 ],
 [ "Brock", 0, 1, 1, 1]         
 ];    

for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++) {
   for(var j=1;j<array1[i][j].length;j++) {
     if(array1[i][j]==100){count100++;}
     else if(array1[i][j]==0){count0++;}
     else countrest++; 
   }
}
```

What I want is, I want to loop into each rows, if a particular row that has values like  zero,hundred or rest, then incrementation should take place as follows.

`[ "Jai", 0, 0, 0, 0 ]` then count the `count0++`, that is increment by one.

if 
    `[ "Jai", 0, 1, 0, 1 ]` then count the `countrest++`, that is increment by one or

else
    `[ "Jai", 100, 100, 100, 100 ]` then count the `count100++`, that is increment by one

So, how to get this done. It should only see if a row has only 100 value if only a row is 100 then only increment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick. For each subArray you want to test a few variables are set to true. If it turns out that one of the items is not 0 or not 100, the accompanying variable is set to false. The results are catched and interpreted afterwards.

```
var count0 = 0; var count100 = 0; var countrest = 0;
for(var a = 0 ; a < array1.length ; a++){
    var zero = true; var hundred = true;
    for(var b = 1 ; b < array1[a].length ; b++){
        if(array1[a][b] != 0){zero = false;}
        else if(array1[a][b] != 100){hundred = false;}
    }
    if(zero == true){count0++;}
    else if(hundred == true){count100++;}
    else{countrest++;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the array structure is always the same

```
for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
    if(array1[i][1] == array1[i][2] == array1[i][3] == array1[i][4]){
        if(array1[i][1]==100){count100++;}
        else if(array1[i][1]==0){count0++;}
    }else{
        countrest++; 
    }
}
```

Comment: the structure differ..... it can have more then '5' values in a row...like ["jai",0,1,0,1,0,10,1,50,etc]......

Answer (score 0):

```
for(key in array1){
    if(array1[key].indexOf(100)!=-1){
        count100++;
    }
    else if(array1[key].indexOf(1)!=1){
        countrest++;
    }
    else{
        count0++;
    }
}
```